# @Html.EditorFor DateTime not displaying when set a default value to it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, string-formatting, data-annotations

I'd like to set a default value to my model in Controller, But It cannot display in create page.

TestModel code:

```
public class TestModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime), Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "yyyy/MM/dd", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime), Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "yyyy/MM/dd", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }


    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new TestModel();
    model.StartTime = DateTime.Now;
    model.EndTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
    model.Description = "This is a default value";
    return View(model);
}
```

View page:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartTime)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartTime)
    </div>
</div>
```

But the display is not correct that it is has no default `datetime` value, but the description default value is display correct:
[image]

Comment: the attachment image is the webpage display.

Comment: show `TestModel` class

Comment: You need to show the model. in particular the `[DisplayFormat]` attribute your have applied (the format string is not correct)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to have model class property like below :

```
[DataType(DataType.Date), Required]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date), Required]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
```

When you decorate a model property with `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` the default template in `ASP.NET MVC` generates an input field of `type="date"`.

Answer (score 2):

Your razor would be as follows:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Date, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control",@type = "date"})
```

Comment: [DefaultValue(System.DateTime.Now)]
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

Change the model to :

```
  public class TestModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime), Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime), Required]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }


    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

it is figure out. cause the display format string is not correct.

Comment: There is not need to repeat Rahul Nikate's answer

Answer (score -2):

Use DataAnnotations to st default values:

```
[DefaultValue(System.DateTime.Now)]

public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
```